# operator overload in as3 workarounds

Tags: actionscript-3

I know it's not possible to overload operators in as3, and have been using the get and set functionality (which is brilliant imho), however now I'm in the middle of creating a colour class.

What I'm trying to do is a colour class, and then subtypes rgb,hsl,hsv and so on... my problem is when I make these variables how do I make it so when I read their value they appear as a uint?

for example I want to be able to do this.

```
var myRGBcolour:RGB = new RGB(14,21,42);
someSprite.graphics.beginFill(myRGBcolour);     //for those of you who don't know,
                                                //this function expects a uint
```

How can I achieve this?
I was reading earlier about valueof functions but from what I can understand, you can only use that if you say something like `myRGBcolour.valueOf()` but that defeats the entire purpose, I might as well just make a `myRGBcolour.toUint()` function.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: So you want to pass your class as an argument and have it automatically become an uint? Also please explain, what would be the disadvantage of creating and using a toUint function?

Comment: I agree with EyeSeeEm - why is calling a method on the color class defeating the whole purpose?

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear, I just thought there might be a cleaner way to do it than using a getter function is all. I guess there isn't one though. Thank's for everyone's help. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to override valueOf and make specific cast:

```
someSprite.graphics.beginFill(0+myRGBcolour); // 0+ is similar to 0x
```

or if you prefer:

```
someSprite.graphics.beginFill(myRGBcolour+0);
```

This construction is used in [Fingers](http://filimanjaro.com/fingers)

Comment: BTW: I wrote an article about operator's overloading in AS3: http://filimanjaro.com/2012/operators-overloading-in-as3-javascript-too-%E2%80%93-workaround/

Comment: thank's but it seems like your settling for "new O() + 0;" at the end anwyays...lol

Comment: No, if you're using +, you don't need 0.

Answer (score 2):

beginFill() takes a uint, so you gotta give it one. I think having a toUint method sounds like the best plan, or having a get property.